# How to combine css :hover with :not

Tags: css

There is a similar question already, but that question uses nested elements.  My scenario is a bit different.  I want to create a glow effect on a menu item when the user hovers over the row, but not if the row also has a "disabled" class.

This is my HTML

```
<tr class='menubaroption disabled'><td>Client</td></tr>
```

Here's my css

```
.menubaroptions tr.menubaroption:hover :not(.disabled) td{
   opacity:1;
   text-shadow:0 0 5px #fff,0 0 10px #fff,0 0 20px #fff,0 0 40px #0ff,0 0 80px #0ff
}
```

I've tried variations of this but I can't seem to get it to work.  Without the :not(.disabled) all menu items have the hover effect, but if I put in the :not (as in this example) it removes the hover effect from **all** menu items, even those without the disabled class.  What's the trick here?

Comment: Remember that space has meaning in such CSS selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the space between the :hover and :not. So something like this:

```css
.menubaroptions tr.menubaroption:hover:not(.disabled) td {
   opacity:1;
   text-shadow:0 0 5px #fff,0 0 10px #fff,0 0 20px #fff,0 0 40px #0ff,0 0 80px #0ff;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You only need to remove the space between both pseudo-classes `:hover :not`

```css
div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
}

div:hover:not(.disabled) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div class="disabled"></div>
```

Comment: This may have worked at one point, but no longer does. When you run the code snippet, both divs are red.